# Profiler that logs arguments of dll

Tags: dll, profiling

Is there a profiler(or similar program) that will log the function calls and arguments sent to a dll.  By arguments I mean the data sent to the function; not the data type of the argument.

For example say I have

---

dll

```
int myAdd(int a, int b)
    return( a+b )
```

main

```
int a = myAdd(1, 2)
int b = myAdd(3,4) 
int c = myAdd(5,6)
```

---

I'd want the profiler to log:
  myAdd was called with (1,2)
  myAdd was called with (3,4)
  myAdd was called with (5,6)

Brian

Comment: Are you doing this for performance tuning?

Answer (score 0):

That's what ltrace does in linux. Maybe googling for "ltrace for windows" yields something...